# Using Microsoft.Web.Administration Application to change authentication mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I would like to change the authentication mode of a web site or application in IIS from Anonymous to Windows and Basic via C# code using Microsoft.Web.Administration. The executing code is not the code of the web application but an external tool. How do I do that?

Comment: Microsoft documentation already contains sample code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/anonymousauthentication#c Follow the convention, you can disable anonymous authentication and enable Windows and basic authentication methods

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use below code to enable windows authentication by using c sharp code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample {

    private static void Main() {
        
        using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
            
            ConfigurationSection windowsAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication", "htmlsite");
            windowsAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = true;
            
            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

disable anonymous authentication:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample {

    private static void Main() {
        
        using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
            
            ConfigurationSection anonymousAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", "htmlsite");
            anonymousAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = false;
            
            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```